# Accessibility Inspector not working on Xcode 11.x, iOS 13.x on MacOS Catalina & Mojave

Tags: xcode, accessibility, ios

I am unable to inspect any elements using the Accessibility Inspector on iOS 13.2 and higher simulators running on Mac OS Mojave or Catalina. Has anyone else also encountered this issue and if so, is there a solution to this? I did not encounter this issue on iOS 12 Simulators, though.

Comment: Did you added/enabled Xcode to have Full Disk Access in Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Security ?

Comment: I tried that, restarted the machine, but no luck. Anything else that needs to be done besides what you mentioned above?

Comment: same situation for me. I tried switching the xcode version using xcode-select, rebooting macOS, allowing the Full Disk Access to XC but nothing helps. It used to work fine a couple of days ago ..